# Javascript get array of objects from array of objects in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array with registrations, inside this array is an array of students.
Now I want an array of all the students with only firstName, lastName and email.

registrations array

```
[
  0: {
    date: "2019-04-08T13:51:10.215Z"
    onlyVAT: false,
    students: [
      0: {
        email: "ben@test.be",
        firstName: "Bennn",
        lastName: "test",
        phone: "0898989"
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I have so far:

```
 this.registrations.map(
    registration => registration.students.map(
        student => { return {
          firstName: student.firstName,
          lastName: student.lastName,
          email: student.email
          }}
      )
    );
```

but this returns an array of arrays

```
0: [
  0: {firstName: "Bennn", lastName: "test", email: "ben@test.be"},
  1: ...
]
```

what I want is an array of (partial) student objects

```
[
  0: {firstName: "Bennn", lastName: "test", email: "ben@test.be"},
  1: ...
]
```

ofcourse I could just loop and push to a new array but that's not what I want

Comment: Don't forget to assign the `map` result, it looks like it's not.

Comment: Should those be *all* student records from *all* registrations? Are there any duplicates? If yes, should they be removed?

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg It should be all students from all registrations, there are no duplicates, however, an examples that includes the removing of duplicates would be nice too!

Comment: also I don't know if this is the fastest solution, should I use filter instead?

Comment: @Ruben : if duplicates removal may be required, my [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56789190/11299053) may do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flat()` or `flatMap()`. Example:

```
  const newArr = registrations.map(
    registration => registration.students.map(
      student => { return {
        firstName: student.firstName,
        lastName: student.lastName,
        email: student.email
      }}
    )
  ).flat();

  console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `flatMap`.

```
this.registrations.flatMap(...);
```

Or use `reduce`:

```
this.registrations.map(...).reduce((a, c) => [...a, c], []);
```

Comment: You can use `[...a, c]` instead of `a.concat(c)`  

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with two `Array.reduce()` functions and `Object.values()`, which will ensure that the output will contain only unique emails (in the example input I have two identical emails `ben4@test.be`):

```js
const registrations = [
  {
    date: '2019-04-08T13:51:10.215Z',
    onlyVAT: false,
    students: [
      {
        email: 'ben@test.be',
        firstName: 'Bennn',
        lastName: 'test',
        phone: '0898989'
      },
      {
        email: 'ben2@test.be',
        firstName: 'Bennn2',
        lastName: 'test2',
        phone: '0898989'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    date: '2019-05-08T13:51:10.215Z',
    onlyVAT: false,
    students: [
      {
        email: 'ben3@test.be',
        firstName: 'Bennn3',
        lastName: 'test3',
        phone: '0898989'
      },
      {
        email: 'ben4@test.be',
        firstName: 'Bennn4',
        lastName: 'test4',
        phone: '0898989'
      },
      {
        email: 'ben4@test.be',
        firstName: 'Bennn4',
        lastName: 'test4',
        phone: '0898989'
      }
    ]
  }
];


const result = registrations.reduce((res, {students}) => ({
  ...res,
  ...students.reduce((res2, {email, firstName, lastName}) => ({
    ...res2,
    [email]: {email, firstName, lastName}
  }), {})
}), {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

The result is obtained in such form since `students` is a field inside an object in the array.

You could simply apply a combination of `concat` and `...` spread operator on the result obtained from map to get the final array of students.

```
const studentsMapped = this.registrations.map(
    registration => registration.students.map(
        student => { return {
            firstName: student.firstName,
            lastName: student.lastName,
            email: student.email
       }}
    )
);

const students = [].concat(...studentsMapped);
```